# Chrome Debugging in Android L

Tags: android, adb, google-chrome-devtools, android-5.0-lollipop

I've got Android L on my Nexus 5, and I'm trying to debug a mobile website using the Chrome Desktop ADB plugin, but I get an error saying

**You may need a newer version of desktop Chrome. Please try Chrome 36.0.1985.65 or later.**

Yet when I check for update (in the desktop version) I get

**Version 35.0.1916.153 m, Google Chrome is up to date.**

Anyone know if there's anyway around this? Or do I just have to wait until the desktop browser catches up to my phones version?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like `36.0.1985.103` was added to the Beta Channel on June 30 2014. Make your Desktop version of Chrome use the [Beta channel](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/beta.html):

http://googlechromereleases.blogspot.de/2014/06/beta-channel-update_30.html

Comment: Whoops, my user account doesn't have the rights to install the beta :P. I'll throw this problem over to IT. Cheers!